# Non-parametric effect size

Tags: nonparametric, effect-size

**Effect size**, as estimated by **Cohen's $\delta$**, is:

> $d=\frac{\hat x_1 - \hat x_2}{\hat s_{pooled}}$

Since the numerator is an estimate of difference in **location**, and the denominator is an estimate of the **spread**, I have always thought it reasonable to replace the top with difference in medians and the bottom with interquartile range:

> $m=\frac{Median(X_1) - Median(X_2)}{IQR(X_1\ and\ X_2)}$

But I cannot find any references to justify this. Does this sound reasonable?

The type of application I'm looking for here is the often encounter situation where I'm doing test of location with small data ($n<20$). I compute the t-statistic and generate its null distribution with permutation. This gives me nice *p*-values. But for numerical estimation of effect magnitude, I thought this $m$ quantity may be helpful in describing the size of the effect magnitude.

Edit: Added clarification

Comment: I haven't heard of this either but if you're in a field of study where medians and IQR are nearly universally used there might be little wrong with this approach. Some simulations could easily demonstrate so. But don't call it anything like `d`. Given that the question is about the reasonableness of the approach you need to add why you do it.

Comment: How about Cohen's U3?

Comment: For what it's worth, sample medians are approximately normally distributed: http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/162/Handouts/MedianThm04.pdf. That reference also derives the density of an arbitrary order statistic, in turn referring to _John E. Freund’s Mathematical Statistics with Applications_, seventh edition, so maybe that book also gives the distribution of a difference in order statistics. Then if it's something "nice" you can derive an analytical distribution for what you proposed

Comment: And this (gated) paper seems to offer a general approach to testing differences in quantiles from different samples http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00362-007-0058-3